# Using R and Ubuntu for crontabs

Tags: r, ubuntu

I would like to run a crontab every day at 12h. So I defined a path to my Script with the following syntax:
`00 12 * * * sudo R CMD BATCH /home/.../test.R`

In order to test that I just ran:

```
sudo R CMD BATCH /home/.../test.R
```

And get the message:

```
basename: extra operand ‘.R’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

I tried many combinations but nothing seems to work. Maybe one has an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which is in Ubuntu, on CRAN and available in source.

I have been using it for 7+ years to power the (now bi-hourly) [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries/) cron job. For that particular one I have

```
# every few hours, run cranberries
11 */2 * * *    edd     ~/cranberries/cranberries.r
```

in `/etc/crontab`. You write a first line of `#!/usr/bin/env r` so that `r` from littler is found, do `chmod 0755 nameOfThatFile.r` and now can execute the file.

Of course, you could also use Rscript.  For both, lots of other questions here provide examples.

Oh, and you probably should not run R jobs as `root`...  But your error is with `sudo`: you need `sudo -c "cmd arg1 arg2 arg3"`.  But then you don't need `sudo` as you could just have the job run as `root`. But as I said, "don't do that...".

Comment: `Warning in install.packages :
   package ‘littler’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)` Hmm Do I something wrong?

Comment: Your R version is old. You can do either an upgrade of R, or install littler from CRAN. Both are described in [the README for Ubuntu on CRAN](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu).  But because `littler` has been in Debian and Ubuntu for years, just do this on the shell:  `sudo apt-get install littler`.

Comment: Hi thank you. Do I have to excecute the `R` file from `etc/crontab`as well?

Comment: I just was confused about `cranberries.r` and `nameOfThatFile.r`

Comment: No I actually installed littler und uses it :)

Comment: Nice. One happy user at a time :)